# my own Stack class debugs

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I'm trying to build my own Stack class and there is bug i push some characters and it pops strange characters
implementation using linked list to create and Stack data structure
here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    char symbol;
    struct node* next;
};

class Stack
{
    struct node* head;
    public:
        Stack(){
        head=NULL;
}

void push(char s)
{
    if(emp()){
        head=new node();
        head->symbol=s;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node* nod=new node();
        nod->next=head;
        nod->symbol=s;
        head=nod;
        free(nod);
    }
}

char pop()
{
    char temp=0;
    if(!emp()){
        struct node* p=head->next;
        temp=head->symbol;
        free(head);
        head=p;
        free(p);
        return temp;
    }
}

bool emp()
{
    if(head==NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

~Stack(){while(!emp())pop();}

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    Stack s;
    s.push('1');
    s.push('2');
    cout << s.pop()<<endl;
    cout << s.pop()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I push characters '1' and '2'
pop's result strange characters!

Answer (score 0):

```
void push(char s)
{
    if(emp()){
        head=new node();
        head->symbol=s;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node* nod=new node();
        nod->next=head;
        nod->symbol=s;
        free(nod);
    }
}
```

If the stack is not empty you delete the node  once you put it on the stack with the `free(nod)` line. So when you call `pop()` head is pointing to a deleted object. So don't do any freeing or deleting in your `push()` function.

Futhermore you should not use `free` for objects created with the `new` keyword use `delete nod;` instead.

The pop method also looks a little crazy: You free the head, and then free the next node in the stack. Try something like this, where you only delete the head object:

```
char pop()
{
    char tempChar = 0;
    if( !emp() )
    {
        struct node* tempNode = head->next;
        tempChar = head->symbol;
        // delete the object pointed to by head
        delete head;
        // assign the head to the next node in the stack
        head = tempNode;
    }
    // still need to return something even if the stack is empty
    return tempChar;
}
```

Comment: what is different between delete and free i just wanted to remove the pointer not the node. node must still be pointed at by head->next

Comment: Free is only used for malloc'd memory, which is normally something used in C and avoided in C++. You don't need to delete a pointer itself since technically it's just a numeric type that holds the memory address for the object it's pointing to, this will get cleaned up when it goes out of scope. You only need to delete the things you create with `new` and only when you're done using them. So don't do any deleting in your push function, only do the deleting in the pop function when you're done using the node.

Comment: and if it is empty why should i return tempNode=0 ?

Comment: You've defined that the function `pop()` will return a `char`. If you turn up the warnings on your compiler it should give a warning message about this. You can return whatever value you want when the stack is empty but you need to return a char. If this isn't something you want then you may need to think about implementing a way for `pop()` telling the user the stack is empty, maybe by throwing an exception or you could pass in a char pointer which `pop( char* output )` will assign to the value if the stack is not empty, else it will assign the pointer to `NULL`

Comment: or i can start tempNode =' ';
so when returning empty node nothing can be displayed

Comment: Yup that's fine, you can return any char value there. But checking if `' '` is the value that's returned from the `pop()` function is not a solid check to see if the stack is empty since you may have pushed the `' '` character onto the stack. Best to check your `emp()` function before calling `pop()`